# Adding Cron Task, what does 'path/to/artisan' mean?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Im just wondering what the `path/to/artisan` part means, in the command:

`* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Is it that path to the command from he `C:/` drive?? for example:

`C:/.../path/to/command/mycommand`

or is it the path when inside the project folder?

`app/commnds/mycommand`

or am I not getting it and it is something different? Sorry im just a bit confused with this.

Thanks!

Also, I am on Windows, `crontab -e` will not work and I am working on a localhost server running on wamp64.

Comment: it means where is your laravel project. for example in centos is like this: /var/www/html/project_name

Comment: Okay that makes sense...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its mean the [`Artisan`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan) file**

there are an artisan file inside your laravel project.

just add the exact path of this file

Reference: [php artisan schedule:run](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/how-to-perform-php-artisan-schedulerun-on-an-ubuntu-server-with-laravel-53-for-cron-jobs)

Answer (score 0):

```
* * * * * php { your laravel project folder }/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Thats what it means.